# Как вытащить данные из таблицы,чтоб в дальнейшем их отправить в БД

Tags: php, html, sql

```
        <table border="1px">
        <tr>
          <th>Canopy Name</th><th>Canopy Size</th><th>Reserved Name</th><th>Reserved Size</th><th>Pack Name</th><th>Pack Size</th><th>ADD</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo "$Cname" ?></td><td><?php echo "$CSize" ?></td><td><?php echo "$Rname" ?></td><td><?php echo "$RSize" ?></td><td><?php echo "$Pname" ?></td><td><?php echo "$PSize" ?></td><td><?php echo "$Add" ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="submit">Подтвердить</button>
```

Comment: Не могу найти нигде ответ или не понимаю ответы, как из ячейки таблицы HTML вытащить данные, которые отображаются из кода php. Немного не понимаю, как теперь задать переменные... для дальнейшего занесения их в БД

Answer (score 0):

```
Если подключен:
     1. jQuery: $('table').find('td').html(); //ради примера
     2. JS:  var table = document.getElementById("table"); 
             var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
             var tds = trs.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
     3. PHP: $dom = new DOMDocument;
             $dom->loadHTML($html);
             $tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

             foreach ($tds as $td) {
                 echo $td->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
             }
```

---

По хорошему установите id, class, name или уж data-attr к значениям, которые вы в дальнейшем хотите выбирать.

Но в вашем случае, думаю можно заюзать обычную форму, судя по кнопке подтвердить, тогда они придут вам в $_POST - глобальный массив, который именно для этого и существует.